# WAMP style server deployment/installation questions

Tags: php, mysql, apache, deployment, installation

So I have a WAMP server setup on my development machine using wampserver which i want to deploy on a standard windows pc through a single installation package. 

I'll be using NSIS to make the installation file. 

I need to know a few things:

1. Should I install apache,php,mysql individually or use something like wampServer (which I am using on the dev machine)?

2. Do I need to check for pre-existing installations of Apache,mysql and/or php? If so, what should I do if I find them?

3. Should I do silent installs or call the individual installers for each

4. Is there anything I need to do so that I don't require a restart for everything to be ready to go?

5. I will have to replace/modify the default config files with my own of course, can I do this with an install script before I install apache/php/mysql, I think I read somewhere that apache doesn't override existing config files, not sure about the others.

Is there anything else I am not taking into consideration? Basically I want the installation to be as automated as possible and I definitely want to avoid things like the mysql server setup which would be pretty silly in an already made server install package. 
I'm new with web development in general and I have also never made an installation file before so that is why I have so many questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It depends, using wamp makes it very simple, if you want the latest versions of everything then you're going to have to install everything separately.
2. You would need to check for existing versions, or you could end up with, for instance, two versions of mysql running at the same time. As to what you do, that's entirely up to you. If you want everything to be the same on every machine (something I'd recommend), I'd delete the existing installs and replace them with the standard versions.
3. Again it depends, if it's an automated script that's already been tested that it works then silent installs will be fine. Although it might give you that warm fuzzy feeling inside to see everything as it's installing.
4. I'm 100% sure nothing you need to install requires a restart. (Thanks @cwallenpoole)
5. If you're installing using wamp I believe all the configuration files will be new. I've never done this myself, but I'd assuming the process would be: install wamp -> overwrite existing config files -> restart all the wamp services.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: 4, I am 100% and you don't need a restart. It is advisable though, just so you can make sure that WAMP starts on startup correctly. 5. They will be new. Anything which needs to modify the conf/ini/htaccess stuff needs to happen *after* installation. Anyway +1, you might want to amend your answer since I'm confirming what you've already suspected, but that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it definitely helped. Is there an easy way to restart services via an installation script? Do you recommend any nsis tutorials that will help me with things like checking for existing versions etc.

Comment: Not sure about checking for existing services. However you can restart using net stop "servicename" and net start "service name"